# Line $l$ is tangent to the curve $y=2-(1/x)$ at the point where $x=p$. Show that an equation of $l$ may be expressed in the form $p^2y-x= 2p^2-2p$.

Tags: derivatives, analytic-geometry, tangent-line

$x$ not equal to $0$. A little confused on how to proceed. I can get as far as taking the derivative to find the slope of the tangent line: $dy/dx=1/x^2$. Not specifically after the answer, just a hint on what to do next.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort. This should be added to the question rather than in the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line has to pass through the point:

$$x_0=p,\quad y_0=2-\frac1{x_0}=2-\frac 1p\tag{1}$$

The slope of the line is defined by the first derivative:

$$y'=\frac{d}{dx}(2-\frac 1x)=\frac1{x^2}$$

At point $(x_0, y_0)$ the value of derivative is:

$$y'_0=\frac1{p^2}\tag{2}$$

Equation of the line passing through the point $(x_0,y_0)$ with slope $y'_0$ is:

$$y-y_0=y'_0 (x-x_0)\tag{3}$$

Replace (1) and (2) into (3) and you are done.